# AngularJS delay Route change after transitions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, gsap

I have enter and leave (javascript) animations on ng-view.  When the location changes I would like to animate out multiple elements in the current view, then, when those animations are completed, trigger the 'enter' animations on the new view. Is there a way to achieve this type of sequencing without overriding ngRoute ? Out of the box, enter and leave animations are triggered at the same time when the location changes.

Angular 1.2+
Greensock JS animation library

Comment: you could add delays to enter animation enough to simulate a sequence

Comment: Yeah that's how I'm doing it now.  I just though there would be a better way